# Excel C&P Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have an order form I have created. The details of the form are inputted manually. I would like to create a macro that takes the cells/data and copies them in to another worksheet to keep a record of the information and freeing up the order form to be used again.

I have recorded a macro that will do this, however each time I run the macro it will overwrite the last copied form. How can I get Excel to paste the data in to free cells below rather than overwrite the previously copied data?

```
 ' CP Macro
'

'
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("B2:E19").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:E19").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet7").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`  (that's all one line).  You may have to adjust the `Offset` if you don't have data in every row of the first column.

Answer (score 2):

The code below finds the lowest populated row in `sheet7` no matter what column it is in and then goes one row lower.  It starts the paste in the A column of the row below the lowest row with contents.

```
Sub test()
dim lastrow as integer  


lastrow = Sheets("sheet7").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("sheet7").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1
Sheets("sheet3").Select
Range("B2:E19").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("sheet7").Select
Cells(lastrow, 1).Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit


End Sub
```

A cleaner and more efficient way to accomplish the same goal is the use this code:

```
Sub test()
dim lastrow as integer  


lastrow = Sheets("sheet7").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("sheet7").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1  

Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:E19").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet7").Cells(lastrow, "A")

end sub
```